# Javascript get all value of keys in array?

Tags: javascript

How can I get all values of keys in an array **without** jQuery?

```
var species = [{"code_name":"b","public_name":"a"},{"code_name":"d","public_name":"c"},{"code_name":"f","public_name":"e"}];

var speciesVals = Object.keys(species).map(function (val, key) {
    return val;
});
```

Result:

```
[ '0',
  '1',
  '2',
  '_atomics',
  '_parent',
  '_cast',
  '_markModified',
  '_registerAtomic',
  '$__getAtomics',
  'hasAtomics',
  '_mapCast',
  'push',
  'nonAtomicPush',
  '$pop',
  'pop',
  '$shift',
  'shift',
  'pull',
  'splice',
  'unshift',
  'sort',
  'addToSet',
  'set',
  'toObject',
  'inspect',
  'indexOf',
  'remove',
  '_path',
  'isMongooseArray',
  'validators',
  '_schema' ]
```

But I am after:

```
["code_name":["b", "d", "d"], "public_name":["a", "c", "e"]
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

What about this:

`[{"code_name":["b", "d", "d"]}, {"public_name":["a", "c", "e"}]`

Comment: Why not just use a loop? `for( var result = {}, i=0, l=species.length, k; i<l; i++) { for( k in species[i]) if( species[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) { result[k] = result[k] || []; result[k].push(species[i][k]); }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. If your object keys are the same for every object in the array, you can do:

```js
var species = [{"code_name":"b","public_name":"a"},{"code_name":"d","public_name":"c"},{"code_name":"f","public_name":"e"}];
var res = {code_name: [], public_name: []};
   
for(var i = 0; i < species.length; i++){
    res.code_name.push(species[i].code_name);
    res.public_name.push(species[i].public_name);
}

console.log(res);
```

---

EDIT

To get an array of objects:

```js
var species = [{"code_name":"b","public_name":"a"},{"code_name":"d","public_name":"c"},{"code_name":"f","public_name":"e"}];
var res = [{code_name: []}, {public_name: []}];
   
for(var i = 0; i < species.length; i++){
    res[0].code_name.push(species[i].code_name);
    res[1].public_name.push(species[i].public_name);
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, no need to overcomplicate because this is a simple old-school iteration task. :)

Comment: i totally agree with u. was overthinking to .prototype side!

Comment: That makes sense if you plan to do many variations of this (like fetching different keys, using different original array structure, different organization of results, etc.), but if you want a code that solves this single task efficiently, I'd go with a single loop every time.

Comment: cool. thanks for the tip. Btw, how can I make this instead `[{"code_name":["b", "d", "d"]}, {"public_name":["a", "c", "e"}]` - objects in an array?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method.

```js
var species = [{
  "code_name": "b",
  "public_name": "a"
}, {
  "code_name": "d",
  "public_name": "c"
}, {
  "code_name": "f",
  "public_name": "e"
}];

var temp = species.reduce(function(res, v) {
  // iterate over object(array element)
  Object.keys(v).forEach(function(k) {
    // define property as array if not defined
    res[k] = res[k] || [];
    // push the value to prefered array
    res[k].push(v[k]);
  });
  // return the updated object
  return res;
  // define the initial value as object to hold the result
}, {});

// now create your expected result
var speciesVals = Object.keys(temp) // get all property names
  .map(function(v) { //iterate over them to generate the result array
    var obj = {}; // create object for 
    obj[v] = temp[v]; // add property
    return obj; // return object (which is the new array element)
  });


console.log(speciesVals);
```

Comment: thanks. what about this: 

`[{"code_name":["b", "d", "d"]}, {"public_name":["a", "c", "e"}]` ?

Comment: @teelou : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a fixed array for the properties, because you need only `'code_name` and `public_name`.

```js
var species = [{ "code_name": "b", "public_name": "a" }, { "code_name": "d", "public_name": "c" }, { "code_name": "f", "public_name": "e" }],
    speciesVals = {};

species.forEach(function (a) {
    ['code_name', 'public_name'].forEach(function (k) {
        speciesVals[k] = speciesVals[k] || [];
        speciesVals[k].push(a[k]);
    });
});

console.log(speciesVals);
```